Excel VBA: Keep .OFT formatting when replacing data
I'm working on a VBA routine in Excel where I want to open an Outlook template (with formatting) and replace data in the template with data from the spreadsheet.
I'm using Office 2021: Excel 2021 and Outlook 2021 connecting to an Exchange 365 server (GoDaddy).
I am able to open the template. When I Outlook.Display the message, it displays with the formatted text. Alas! When I try to replace ANYTHING in the body of the email with OutMail.body = Replace(OutMail.body, "<>", var) , the template format reverts (converts? Changes?) to text. Replacing text in the TO:, SUBJECT:, CC:, or BCC: fields keeps the formatting. The data is getting to the template.
The relevant code is below. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim eBody As String
Dim CurrentRow As Integer

'Variables for tags in the template
Dim eMailTag, eContactTag, eAddressTag, eDescriptionTag, eValueTag As String

' Set the workbook and worksheet you want to send
' Create a new Outlook instance
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0) ' 0 represents a mail item
Set myolapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
myolapp.Session.Logon
'This is where the OFT template lives. It must be explicitly declared.
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\xxx\Sales\Systems\Proposal_10.oft")

OutMail.display 'or send
OutMail.HTMLBody = OutMail.HTMLBody 'does not work with or without this line.
' Get the data from the spreadsheet and assign the cels to the tag variables
MsgBox ("check the email...")
Sheets("Pipeline").Select
With ActiveSheets
    eMailTag = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 8)
    eContactTag = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 6)
    eAddressTag = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 4)
    eDescriptionTag = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 5)

    eValueTag = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 14)
    'if you add more tags, the assignments go here.
End With

' Replace the data in the template
With OutMail
    .bodyformat = olFormatRichText
    OutMail.To = eMailTag 'Still formatted here.

    OutMail.Subject = "Proposal: " & eDescriptionTag 'Still formatted here...
    .body = Replace(.body, "<<EMAIL>>", eMailTag)  'after this statement, the email .body is plain text.

    OutMail.body = Replace(OutMail.body, "<<RECIPIENT>>", eContactTag)
    OutMail.body = Replace(OutMail.body, "<<ADDRESS>>", eAddressTag)
    OutMail.body = Replace(OutMail.body, "<<DESCRIPTION>>", eDescriptionTag)
    OutMail.body = Replace(OutMail.body, "<<VALUE>>", eValueTag)
End With

' MsgBox (OutMail.body)
' OutMail.display 'or send

' Clean up
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub

I've tried using with and without the olFormatRichText line, with and without olFormatHTML, changing the default message type in Outlook to Rich Text (and HTML)., moving lines around, displaying the mail object at various places in the code.

Typically I think if you're working with rich text mail you'd use the Word object model to perform the replacements. See for example  http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?57090-Need-help-with-OutlookVBA-for-finding-and-replacing-the-text-from-original-email

That does not work.  As soon as I replace anything in the .body, the email format changes from Rich Text (or HTML) to plain text.  All formatting (fonts, bold, etc.) goes away.

It does (can) work - see my answer below.

Here's a very basic example of what I was referring to in my comment:
Sub ReplaceTester()

    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object, doc As Object
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    'template is in rich text format...
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Temp\Proposal_10.oft")
    
    OutMail.Display 'or send
    
    Set doc = OutMail.GetInspector.WordEditor()
    
    ReplaceText doc, "<<TEST>>", "This replaces that"
    ReplaceText doc, "<<TEST2>>", "Something else"
    
End Sub

Sub ReplaceText(doc As Object, lookFor As String, replaceWith As String)
    With doc.Range.Find
        .Text = lookFor
        .Replacement.Text = replaceWith
        .Execute Replace:=2 'wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub

Before and after replacements:



After the mail item is created, I reset HTML with OutMail.HtmlBody = OutMail.HtmlBody.
I saw this in another site (I need to test without this statement).
I changed the tags in the template from <<RECIPIENT>> to [Tag]  ([A], [B], [C], etc.).
Something like: .HtmlBody = Replace(.HtmlBody, "[A]", eAddressTag)

Apparently Outlook does not like double angle brackets to denote replacement text.
I now have an HTML-formatted mail item, ready to send, with [Tag] text replaced with spreadsheet cell values.

Your code is settign the plain text Body property, thus wiping out all formatting. Read and set the HTMLBody property instead.
